# Trim, trimming, and texttrimming tags should be synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

- [trim](/questions/tagged/trim) (221 questions, and a nice wiki)
- [trimming](/questions/tagged/trimming) (29 questions)
- [texttrimming](/questions/tagged/texttrimming) (13 questions)

I think it goes without saying.

Comment: Migrate to bodyhygiene.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The closest we have now I think is fitness.stackexchange.com

Comment: That could work, too ;)

Comment: And `[texttrimming]` should definitely be `[text-trimming]`. Hyphens don't cost any extra...